# Having trouble submitting a form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

HTML:

```
<form id="message">
  <input id="message-text" name="message" type="text" value="" autofocus="autofocus" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // submit new message
    var request;
    $("#message").submit(function(event) {
        // abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var $form = $(this);
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        var postData = $form.serialize();
        // note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "submit.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: postData
        })
        .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('Success: ' + textStatus, jqXHR);
        })
        .fail(function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('Error: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
    });
});
```

I've confirmed that `submit.php` works when not using AJAX to submit, so I don't think that's the problem. The console log simply says: `Error: error` on line 66: `console.error('Error: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);` which is completely non-descriptive nor helpful... The page also refreshes when I hit enter or click submit, which isn't supposed to happen.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You arent' preventing FORM to submit so request is aborted, not getting enough time to complete

Comment: You have to prevent default form submission ` event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#message").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

...
```

Comment: Thank you. For whatever reason I had it in my mind that was deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you use `submit` input, this is the default behavior of `submit` input, so you have 2 options first is disable the submit using `event.preventDeafult();` on the submit process, or you can easily change your send button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I prepare demo for you please download it from

https://www.dropbox.com/s/24h0o9n08iuvpo1/ajaxdemo.rar

Change as per your requirement. I think it is helpful

Comment: Your answer is expected to include all of the necessary information inside the answer, not behind a link. Links should provide supplementary/additional information, but shouldn't be the entire basis of your answer.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGrist. I am new in stackoverflow so, i will be careful next time.